# How can I setup RBL on Plesk?

Tags: spam-filter

Anyone know how to setup RBL in Plesk?

I've Plesk 8.3 with a Centos 5 installed on a VPS. The Plesk panel setup only few option but no RBL. I already have Plesk configured with Spamassasin over Qmail.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to install it.

Using the Plesk Update Manager, look to install "psa-qmail-rblsmtpd", it might also be referred to as some variant of "Spam Blocker for QMail" or "Real-time Blackhole List client for qmail".

After you have installed it, enable it and configure it - should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The best advice I can give you is to use [Spamdyke](http://spamdyke.org) with qmail. It is intercepting SMTP connections before the qmail server and processes DNSBL lookups (plus other neat things).

It is very fast and it's definitely worth to a look.